# Come si chiama un negozio dove si vende pane?

Tags: vocabulary

A volte succede che mi manca il vocabolario  adeguato per esprimere i fatti della vita quotidiana. Come dovrei chiamare un negozio dove si vende pane?

- Forno.
- Panetteria.
- Negozio di pane.
- Negozio del panettiere.
- Dal panettiere.
- Panificio (se il pane si produce nello stesso negozio).
- Altri?

Consultando un dizionario, ho la sensazione che si possano usare tutti o quasi tutti questi termini, ma non ne sono del tutto sicura e non so se dovrei utilizzare uno o altro dipendendo dalle caratteristiche del negozio.

Comment: Penso dipenda da usi e preferenze regionali, personalmente “dal panettiere” è l’espressione che userei tra tutte.

Comment: Anche il termine forno indica un posto che non solo *vende* pane, ma lo *fa* anche sul posto, invece che essere solo una rivendita di pane fatto altrove (ma non tutti notano questa differenza).

Comment: "Vado dal panettiere" o "vado in panetteria". A Milano è comune anche "vado dal prestinaio".

Comment: Empiricamente, tutti suonano familiari, ma un po' meno le perifrasi con “negozio”. A me, poi, il “forno” oltre a significare – come osserva giustamente Federico – che lì il pane lo si produce, dà l'idea di un assortimento più ricco: anche pizza a taglio, piccola gastronomia, magari pasticceria etc. Ma, ripeto, può essere dovuto alla mia esperienza personale; per esempio già la diffusione della pizza a taglio varia da regione a regione.

Comment: Manca  alla lista il fornaio https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fornaio/

Comment: Come già detto la diffusione varia a seconda delle zone, io ad esempio userei fornaio o panettiere ("panetteria" meno, "panificio" dà più un'idea di produzione, anche senza vendita al dettaglio, "prestinaio" dubito varchi i confini lombardi, "forno" per indicare l'intero negozio, per quanto ovviamente comprensibile, non l'ho mai sentito). Concordo con @Dag sulle perifrasi con "negozio": suonano un po' forzate.

Comment: @OldManofAran Nella mia famiglia si è sempre detto “andare al forno”.

Comment: Nella mia si è sempre detto “andare dal fornaio ”. Forno ha un che di antico, forse manzoniano. Penso non ci sia una risposta alla domanda, le espressioni sono varie e geograficamente caratterizzate. Senza contare che ormai molti comperano il pane al supermercato.

Comment: Da me si è sempre chiamato "panificio" o "panetteria" (se il pane non lo fanno). Ma io direi "vado a prendere/comprare il pane", senza nominare il negozio.

Comment: @DaG Quand'ero piccolo (meno di sei anni), andavo a comprare il pane: si trattava di uscire di casa e percorrere circa quindici metri del marciapiede per entrare nel negozio di un amico di famiglia: Forno Bacchin (c'è ancora, lo gestisce uno che ci lavorava da quando aveva quattordici anni). All'epoca si trovava pane (le coppie ferraresi di Marino le sento ancora in bocca), pane biscotto, grissini, pinsa e poco altro. Quella *pinsa* non ha niente a vedere con quella romana, per intenderci; poteva essere *pinsa dolce* o *pinsa onta*.

Comment: È comune in Italia che un "negozio di pane" non produca il proprio pane? Qui in Brasile è molto raro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

È una questione regionale. Il termine “ufficiale” è [*panetteria*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/panetteria/). Si può adoperare anche [*panificio*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/panificio/), che propriamente è un posto dove il pane viene anche prodotto, ma il termine è usato anche in senso esteso.

Tuttavia i lombardi lo chiamano [*prestinaio*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/prestinaio/) (con metonimia, molto frequente nell'indicare botteghe, come il *salumiere* per *la bottega del salumiere*). Con analoga metonimia, si sente spesso *panettiere* o *fornaio*.

Personalmente direi *forno* o *panificio*. Il termine *forno* per *il forno del pane* è piuttosto diffuso, visto che anticamente, in molte zone rurali o montane, la farina o l'impasto già preparato venivano affidati a chi gestiva il forno comune per la cottura e il pane durava settimane (o anche mesi).

Nessuno direbbe *il negozio del panettiere*, ma semplicemente *il panettiere*:

> *va' dal panettiere/prestinaio/fornaio e compra un chilo di rosette*

*Negozio di pane* mi sembra da escludere. Ci sono qua e là esercizi con insegne del tipo *La bottega del pane*, ma è solo per darsi un tono.

---

Il termine *panificio* indica anche un'azienda o un luogo dove si produce pane, ma non lo si vende, perché è destinato alla grande distribuzione. Non molti anni fa, la mia università acquisì e restaurò quello che per molto tempo era stato *il panificio* delle forze armate per una gran parte dell'Italia settentrionale; durante la prima guerra mondiale fu un elemento essenziale, visto che il fronte non era distante dopo l'ottobre 1917. Curiosità: quella struttura era stata costruita dagli austriaci per rifornire il famoso [*Quadrilatero*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortezze_del_Quadrilatero) e ultimata pochi mesi prima della cessione del Veneto all'Italia (1866). Nei silos del grano ora ci sono aule.