# Different terms for bakery. Do they have slightly different meanings?

Tags: vocabulary

I think this is related to my question about [multiple words for coffee shop](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14111/four-ways-to-say-coffee-shop-is-there-a-difference-between-these-terms).

I've come across three different words for bakery. I think I've deduced the correct meanings but would like to make sure I'm correct in my assumptions.

1. la panetteria: I'm assuming this is a bakery/pastry shop.
2. il panificio: I'm assuming this is a bakery/bread shop.
3. il forno: I know this is the word for oven. I've also seen it in some of my books as bakery. I assume it means the baking area where the ovens are vs a bakeshop.

I'm assuming la panetteria and il panificio are similar to French in the sense that in France there are patisseries and boulangeries. I'm in the United States and bakery is a universal term that coverers both pastry shops and bread shops.

Am I correct in my assumptions? Are there other terms in Italian for bakery/bake shop?

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13288/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *panetteria* is a shop that sells bread and other baked food; a *panificio* is a place that makes (*-ficio* has the same origin as *fare*) bread etc., and often sells it too (and sometimes the word is used to mean what actually is just a shop); *forno*, as well as meaning oven – as you say – is also often used to mean a *panificio*.

Many larger *panetterie* also have pastries and other sweet baked goods, but that's actually what *pasticcerie* are for.

Note that all of the above, and more, can be found in a good monolingual dictionary. For instance: [panetteria](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/panetteria/), [panificio](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/panificio) and [forno](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/forno).